# Qwt and boost::signals

Tags: qt, boost, compiler-errors, signals, qwt

My project is using both Qt (included Qwt) and Boost::signals. As known, their macros are incompatible with each other. I compiled my project with `CONFIG += no_keywords` and renamed all Qt macros with upper-case registry i.e. `signals = Q_SIGNALS`. There are no more errors in project, but now I have errors in Qwt includes like this

```
/usr/include/qwtplot3d/qwt3d_extglwidget.h:101:1: error: ‘signals’ does not name a type
/usr/include/qwtplot3d/qwt3d_extglwidget.h:116:8: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘slots’
/usr/include/qwtplot3d/qwt3d_extglwidget.h:116:8: error: ‘slots’ does not name a type
```

It seems that Qwt is still conflicting with Boost::signals. What can I do here?

Comment: Do you mean older Boost.Signals or Boost.Signals2? I used the latter with Qt and didn't encounter any problems.

Comment: Yes, I am using old version of Boost::signals 1.46 and Qt 4.7.4

Comment: Consider moving to Boost.Signals2. It doesn't have the above issues and offers much better slot tracking mechanism.

Comment: Well, it will not help i think, cause i use boost::signals::connection in my project.

Comment: use boost::signals2::connection instead.

Answer (score 1):

Qwt is compatible with boost signals - you are talking about a lib called QwtPlot3D !

When you want to use boost signals with QwtPlot3D you have to patch its implementation replacing the signal/slot/emit macros like you did it with your code.

Comment: I know about this variant, but trying to find another decision.
Right now, i am trying to do things like this:

#undef QT_NO_KEYWORDS
#include <boost/signals.hpp>
#define QT_NO_KEYWORDS no_keywords

And compiling project with CONFIG += no_keywords

Comment: btw, not only qwtplot3d but also other parts of qwt i.e.:
/usr/include/qwt/qwt_picker.h:290:1: error: ‘signals’ does not name a type

Comment: Previous suggestion did not help.

Comment: The offending line in qwt_picker.h is from Qwt 5.2 what is very outdated. More recent versions of Qwt don't use the conflicting keywords anymore. But when you have a look in the admin directory of Qwt 5.2 you find a script that does the renaming you need ( on systems where you have sed available ). You could adopt it for the QwtPlot3D files.

Comment: Well, ok i will try this, but right now im using rpmbuild and mock to rebuild qwt. I changed all macros using sed. Lets see what happens.